# Is it possible to allow anonymous users to view a temporary managed file via hook_file_download()?

Tags: files

I am creating a live image preview system for customizable products that needs to send a user's temporary file to a remote server.

I have a token-based system to protect the file but the problem seems to be that the file is temporary. I've created a hook_file_download() to return the headers as required to allow access when approved but the file access is still being denied somewhere.

It does not seem to be a module weight issue as I've made my custom module have the lowest weight and verified via debug code that it fires after core file_file_download()

EDIT: Further troubleshooting shows the the headers array is getting a key value set to "-1" somewhere after hook_file_download() and core "FileDownloadController" which is where the file is getting denied. Any ideas where this [0] = -1 header value is getting set and how to override it?

If I strip it down to the basics for testing as shown below the 'allow' headers are returned but the file is still being blocked when viewed from an anonymous browser:

```
function MYMODULE_file_download($uri) {

  // Check to see if this is a config download.
  $scheme = StreamWrapperManager::getScheme($uri);

  if ($scheme == 'temporary'){
    if ($files = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file')->loadByProperties(['uri' => $uri])){

      $file = reset($files) ?: NULL;
      
      // Access is granted.
      $headers = file_get_content_headers($file);
      return $headers;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary files are handled by [`file_file_download()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_file_download/9.3.x), an implementation of [`hook_file_download()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21file.api.php/function/hook_file_download/9.3.x) done from the File module. The code it uses is the following one.

```php
  // Find out if a temporary file is still used in the system.
  if ($file->isTemporary()) {
    $usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
    if (empty($usage) && $file->getOwnerId() != \Drupal::currentUser()
      ->id()) {
      // Deny access to temporary files without usage that are not owned by the
      // same user. This prevents the security issue that a private file that
      // was protected by field permissions becomes available after its usage
      // was removed and before it is actually deleted from the file system.
      // Modules that depend on this behavior should make the file permanent
      // instead.
      return -1;
    }
  }
```

Reading the comments, that is done on purpose to avoid a private file, protected by field permissions, is visible after the field permissions are changed, but before the file is deleted.

Looking at the code that invokes that hook, in [`FileDownloadController::download()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21FileDownloadController.php/function/FileDownloadController%3A%3Adownload/9.3.x) for example, I don't see any way to avoid that, as the code doesn't use `hook_file_download_alter()`.

A workaround could be setting that file as being used, since the code checks the file is not used, before blocking the access.

```php
function mymodule_file_download($uri) {
  if (StreamWrapperManager::getScheme($uri) == 'temporary') {
    if ($files = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file')->loadByProperties(['uri' => $uri])){
      if ($file = reset($files)) {
        // Access is granted.
        \Drupal::service('file.usage')->add($file, 'mymodule', 'unexisting_entity', 10);
        $headers = file_get_content_headers($file);
        return $headers;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used `'unexisting_entity'` and 10 as entity type and entity ID. If you have real values for them, you should use those.

Note that [`FileUsageBase::add()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21FileUsage%21FileUsageBase.php/function/FileUsageBase%3A%3Aadd/9.3.x), the [`DatabaseFileUsageBackend::add()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21FileUsage%21DatabaseFileUsageBackend.php/function/DatabaseFileUsageBackend%3A%3Aadd/9.3.x) parent method, changes the file to permanent, in the case it is not already.

```php
// Make sure that a used file is permanent.
if (!$file->isPermanent()) {
  $file->setPermanent();
  $file->save();
}
```

When a file usage is decremented and becomes 0, the file is changed to temporary from [`FileUsageBase::delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21FileUsage%21FileUsageBase.php/function/FileUsageBase%3A%3Adelete/9.3.x).

```php
// If there are no more remaining usages of this file, mark it as temporary,
// which result in a delete through system_cron().
$usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
if (empty($usage)) {
  $file->setTemporary();
  $file->save();
}
```

I would rather increase the file usage, instead of making directly a file permanent, as decreasing the file usage doesn't conflict with other modules that could set the same file as permanent.
Alternatively, I would use the following code for `hook_file_download()`.

```php
function mymodule_file_download($uri) {
  if (StreamWrapperManager::getScheme($uri) == 'temporary') {
    if ($files = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file')->loadByProperties(['uri' => $uri])){
      if ($file = reset($files)) {
        // Access is granted.
        if (!$file->isPermanent()) {
          $file->setPermanent();
          $file->save();
        }
        $headers = file_get_content_headers($file);
        return $headers;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, to make the file temporary again, I would use the following code.

```php
// Store the file entity reference in $file.
$usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
if (empty($usage) && !$file->isTemporary()) {
  $file->setTemporary();
  $file->save();
}
```

To achieve what you want, it would be also possible to change the controller for the *system.temporary* route, but that seems excessive.

Comment: Thank you, yes, that file_file_download() snippet is the culprit. I'm confused as to why I can't use hook_file_download() in my higher weighted module to override that.

Comment: I found a workaround by setting the file to "isPermanent" but I don't like this. Do you know if that will cause files to not be deleted from the system when needed?

Comment: `hook_file_download()` only receives a URL, not the headers returned by other implementations; if this were the case, a hook implementation could override the decision of another implementation. The actual code invoking them just checks one of them returned -1 as header; it doesn't check -1 is the first returned value.

Comment: @quantumized Permanent files will not be removed during the file garbage collection process, but a module could delete them. If the module keeps a list of file it changed to permanent, that could be possible.

Comment: I also added a note about what happens when a file usage is increased: The Drupal core implementation of the *file.usage* service automatically makes a temporary file permanent.